# Error: An item with the same key has already been added while using Ms Enterprise Library CacheManager

Tags: c#

My code is using Micosoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.CacheManager.
Intermittent issue has been reported with error as 'ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added'. I am unable to reproduce the issue therefore not able to provide Stack Trace. What could be the reason of error?? Below is my code and it has both 'lock' and check for key before adding key to Cache. How can I solve this? This code is in a common class file used across pages. Could that be the reason??

CODE -

```
public static CacheManager GetCacheManager(string managerName)
    {
        if (managers.ContainsKey(managerName))
            return managers[managerName];
        else
        {
            lock (managers)
            {
                try
                {
                    CacheManager cm = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(managerName);
                    if (!managers.ContainsKey(managerName))
                        managers.Add(managerName, cm);
                  return cm;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("There was a problem creating the CacheManager '"
                        + managerName + "'. Make sure this CacheManager is properly configured "
                        + "in your application settings file. This includes ensuring the right version "
                        + "of the Microsoft Enterprise Libraries are used. (The PublicKeyToken is correct.)"
                        +  ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```